# Bulk Creating & Bulk Updating ElasticSearch Index Document using Logstash

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash

Documents are not getting updated but are getting newly created instead of updating the document.

COMPANY_ID is a unique column..

SAMPLE DATA

COMPANY_NAME,LOGO_EXT,COMPANY_ID

ABC LIMITED,JPG,ABC000001

XYZ LIMITED,PNG,ABC000002

AAA LLC,,ABC000003

I am able to create the index and the documents.

The problem is when I update the index the document is getting created instead of getting updated.
E.g.
**BEFORE**
ABC LIMITED,JPG,ABC000001

**AFTER**
ABCD LIMITED,JPG,ABC000001

So therefor only COMPANY_NAME should be updated.

**1. Successfully able to create the index using the below code :-**

**BAT FILE**

cd C:\logstash-7.3.1\bin
logstash -f C:\logstash.conf

**C:\logstash.conf FILE**

```
input {  
    jdbc {  
        jdbc_driver_library => "C:\sqljdbc_7.4\enu\mssql-jdbc-7.4.1.jre8.jar"  
        jdbc_driver_class => "com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver"  
        jdbc_connection_string => "jdbc:sqlserver://;user=;password=;"  
        jdbc_user => ""  
        jdbc_password => ""  
        statement => "SELECT COMPANY_NAME,LOGO_EXT,COMPANY_ID from dbo.CompanyMaster WITH(NOLOCK) ORDER BY COMPANY_NAME"  
    }  
}  
filter {}  
output {  
    stdout {  
        codec => json_lines  
    }  
    elasticsearch {  
        hosts => "http://localhost:9200"  
        index => "companylistindex"  
        document_id => "%{COMPANY_ID}"
        action => index
    }  
}
```

**2. Update code**

```
input {  
    jdbc {  
        jdbc_driver_library => "C:\sqljdbc_7.4\enu\mssql-jdbc-7.4.1.jre8.jar"  
        jdbc_driver_class => "com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver"  
        jdbc_connection_string => "jdbc:sqlserver://;user=;password=;"  
        jdbc_user => ""  
        jdbc_password => ""  
        statement => "SELECT COMPANY_NAME,LOGO_EXT,COMPANY_ID from dbo.CompanyMaster WITH(NOLOCK) WHERE ModifiedOn>'2019-11-01'"  
    }  
}  
filter {}  
output {  
    stdout {  
        codec => json_lines  
    }  
    elasticsearch {  
        hosts => "http://localhost:9200"  
        index => "companylistindex"  
        document_id => "%{COMPANY_ID}"
    }  
}
```

Please help me update the document.

Note : Only COMPANY_NAME or LOGO_EXT needs to be updated if different. COMPANY_ID is unique column.

Comment: You need to use [action => update](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-outputs-elasticsearch.html#plugins-outputs-elasticsearch-action). Also, read about [doc_as_upsert](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-outputs-elasticsearch.html#plugins-outputs-elasticsearch-doc_as_upsert)

Comment: I have added action => "update" doc_as_upsert => "true" but still COMPANY_ID is getting duplicated. It should update the record. Do I have to mark {COMPANY_ID} as a primary key when newly creating the index ? Am I missing something...?

Comment: It looks like you have multiple events for same id. You probably need to use [aggregate filter plugin](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-aggregate.html). Also, order by id on sql side and change worker count to 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to the comment suggested by @Polynomial Proton, you no longer need `2` output sections. Just `1` section like below would do:

```
output {  
    stdout {  
        codec => json_lines  
    }  
    elasticsearch {  
        hosts => "http://localhost:9200"  
        index => "companylistindex"  
        document_id => "%{COMPANY_ID}"
        action => "update"
        doc_as_upsert => "true"
    }  
}
```

This will take care of both indexing and updating.

Comment: I have added action => "update" doc_as_upsert => "true" but still COMPANY_ID is getting duplicated. It should update the record. 

Do I have to mark {COMPANY_ID} as a primary key when newly creating the index ? 
Am I missing something...?